# What exactly is the greater condemnation in Matthew 23:14?

Tags: matthew

Matthew 23:14
New American Standard Bible

> "Woe to you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites, because you devour widows' houses, and for a pretense you make long prayers; therefore you will receive **greater condemnation**.

Is there a lesser condemnation? To whom?

Comment: *“And that servant who knew his master’s will but did not get ready or act according to his will, will receive a severe beating. But the one who did not know, and did what deserved a beating, will receive a light beating. Everyone to whom much was given, of him much will be required, and from him to whom they entrusted much, they will demand the more.”
‭‭Luke‬ ‭12:47-48‬* the Greek κριμα could be understood as judgment. A harsher or lighter judgment.

Comment: Most modern English translations omit this verse because it is not found in early MSS (NASB Footnotes)

Comment: A *prima facie* interpretation would be that the comparison is made with their previously mentioned deeds, detailed in the preceding verses (23:1-13).

Comment: Also, Chrysostom's interpretation can be found [here](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf110/npnf110.iii.LXX.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two matters here - one concerns whether Matt 23:14 is actually part of holy Scripture or not - NA27, NA28, USB4, USB5, W&H, etc, all omit this verse.  However, let us assume, for the moment that the verse is valid and answer the other matter - why greater condemnation?

Now, whether Matt 23:14 is valid or not, there are other places in the Bible that have a similar idea:

- Mark 12:40 - "They defraud widows of their houses, and for a show make lengthy prayers. These men will receive **greater condemnation**.”
- Luke 20:47 - "They defraud widows of their houses, and for a show make lengthy prayers. These men will receive **greater condemnation**.”
- James 3:1 - Not many of you should become teachers, my brothers, because you know that we who teach will be judged more strictly [= **greater condemnation**, KJV].

In each case the phrase in question is either περισσότερον κρίμα (Mark 12:40, Luke 20:47), or, μεῖζον κρίμα (James 3:1).

Before proceeding further, we should remind ourselves of the difference between two nouns that are often simplistically translated as "judgement", namely, κρίμα (krima) and κρίσις (krisis).  According the BDAG, the distinction is important:

- κρίμα (krima) is the final decision when the legal process of trail is complete, ie, verdict, condemnation or sentence.
- κρίσις (krisis) is the legal process of judgement, ie, the trial process by which one gathers data and evidence before arriving at a decision.

In the above texts, we are discussing the first meaning - the verdict or sentence received the the guilty against whom Jesus pronounced the "woes", the "scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites".  That is, Jesus is saying that these sinners (in Jesus' eyes) will receive a harsher sentence in the judgement than others.

The reason is not hard to find.  Their sin was much greater precisely because of their privileged position - they had greater knowledge, they could read the holy Scriptures (unlike many), and they were the appointed teachers in Israel.

Note again what James says: "*Not many of you should become teachers, my brothers, because you know that we who teach will be judged more strictly*".

Jesus said something very similar in Luke 12:47, 48:

> That servant who knows his master’s will but does not get ready or
> follow his instructions will be beaten with many blows. But the one
> who unknowingly does things worthy of punishment will be beaten with
> few blows. From everyone who has been given much, much will be
> required; and from him who has been entrusted with much, even more
> will be demanded.

In the case of these pompous, self-sufficient and overtly (but falsely) pious scribes and pharisees, their sin is made much worse because they effectively steal from the poor including widows, etc.  The Expositors Commentary correctly observes (on Mark 12:40)

> In it and the two preceding we have a very slight yet vivid picture of
> Pharisaic piety in its vanity, avarice, and hypocrisy.

I agree.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer, @dottard! Do we have an idea of what this greater judgment is? Are there passages of Scripture that point to how this would unfold practically? What is a greater judgment than separation from God/eternal suffering in hell?

Comment: @Gremosa - according to 1 Thess 1:8-10 that eternal separation as you describe it, or "eternal destruction" in 1 Thess is called "punishment".  The greater condemnation is because of greater responsibilities.  All receive the same punishment of "destruction" but some have a greater condemnation - greater shame of the realisation of how much they have maligned the character and holiness of God.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how greater/lesser condemnation results in identical punishment -- I asked a separate question exploring this further if it's of interest: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/59686/39862

Answer (score 1):

I’ve researched “greater” in context and co-text and I believe that though hell is hell, eternal damnation is eternal damnation- greater indicates that there are degrees of eternal punishment - just as in a prison (no one in their right minds wants to become condemned to prison & I’m definitely not referring to prisons with human rights privileges) I’m speaking about a dark prison- where your bedroom, bathroom and end is a hole with bars and where food and visitors are next to subhuman levels.  Nevertheless , some may allow a few visits a year, just a bit less horrendous food or a small window to get some light. My point is greater is greater and though I don’t care to partake in the “least” of torment as torment is torment + eternal.
God would not have placed GREATER in his word if it wasn’t. Greater judgment or condemnation which certainly translates into greater punishment is self explanatory.
Why complicate punishment when it’s hell and eternal anyways? I certainly don’t look forward to the lesser-because I only qualify for the greater since I know the truth. What I’m 100% sure is that God is righteous and He will pay each one accordingly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/39967)